# Cannot establish tunnel. Exhausted available authentication methods

Tags: ssh, dbeaver

I can connect via ssh to the server
`ssh -i /home/myname/.ssh/2040_db_key ubuntu@my_host`

I am trying to connect to the database with help of DBeaver (my real host replaced with "my_host") [image]

I have an error

```
Cannot establish tunnel to "my_host_ip". 
Exhausted available authentication methods
```

I confident that DB exists
What is wrong with my connection settings?